# iPad Camera Connection Kit - Photo resolution

Tags: ipad, photos, camera

When I send photos from my PC to my iPad through iTunes, there is a pre-processing stage where iTunes reduces the photo size and resolution (I think).

Does this also happen when I use the Camera Connection Kit to add photos from an SD card? If so, does this mean that I will lose the originals if I delete them from the card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iPad Camera Connection Kit is simply a USB hardware interface. It performs no processing and can store raw as well as jpeg from a camera or SD cards.

The iOS photo app will show you the pictures it can, but of you have an exotic raw camera - it will simply hold the images unchanged to deliver to your computer rather than process or change any images.

Comment: I thought that I was only able to import photos from the SD card using the standard Photos app. I don't own a Camera Connection Kit, but I am considering buying one.

Comment: One thing I have found with the Photos app on the new iPad (#3) is that after having imported both 14mp and 5mp images from an SD card I have been unable to tell the difference when viewing the imported images (two images of the same subject). There seems to be a limit on how much you can zoom - both images zoom to the same level. I would have expected to have been able to zoom the 14mp image a lot more, but this does not seem to be the case?! (Unless the images have been processed during _import_?!)